# Batch download google images with tags

Tags: python, image, batch-processing, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I'm trying to find an efficient and replicable way to batch download full-size image files from a Google image search. Other people have asked similar things, but I haven't found anything that's exactly what I'm looking for or that I understand.

Most refer to the depreciated Google Image Search API or the Google Custom Search API which doesn't seem to work for the whole web, or are just about downloading images from a single URL.

I imagine this could be a two step process: First, pull all the image URLs from a search and then batch download from those?

I should add that I am a beginner (which is probably obvious; sorry). So if someone could explain as well as point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

I've also looked into freeware options, but those seem spotty as well. Unless anyone knows of a reliable one.

[Download images from google image search (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133865/download-images-from-google-image-search-python)

[In Python, is there a way I can download all/some the image files (e.g. JPG/PNG) from a **Google Images** search result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035973/in-python-is-there-a-way-i-can-download-all-some-the-image-files-e-g-jpg-png?rq=1)

And if anyone know anything about the labels from this and if they exist somewhere/are associated with the images?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Image_Labeler

```
import json
import os
import time
import requests
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

def go(query, path):
"""Download full size images from Google image search.
Don't print or republish images without permission.
I used this to train a learning algorithm.
"""
BASE_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?'\
         'v=1.0&q=' + query + '&start=%d'

BASE_PATH = os.path.join(path, query)

 if not os.path.exists(BASE_PATH):
 os.makedirs(BASE_PATH)

start = 0 # Google's start query string parameter for pagination.
while start < 60: # Google will only return a max of 56 results.
r = requests.get(BASE_URL % start)
for image_info in json.loads(r.text)['responseData']['results']:
  url = image_info['unescapedUrl']
  try:
    image_r = requests.get(url)
  except ConnectionError, e:
    print 'could not download %s' % url
    continue

  # Remove file-system path characters from name.
  title = image_info['titleNoFormatting'].replace('/', '').replace('\\', '')

  file = open(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, '%s.jpg') % title, 'w')
  try:
    Image.open(StringIO(image_r.content)).save(file, 'JPEG')
  except IOError, e:
    # Throw away some gifs...blegh.
    print 'could not save %s' % url
    continue
  finally:
    file.close()

print start
start += 4 # 4 images per page.

# Be nice to Google and they'll be nice back :)
time.sleep(1.5)

# Example use
go('landscape', 'myDirectory')
```

#### Update

I was able to create a Custom Search using the full web as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated), and successfully execute to get the image links, but as also mentioned in that previous post, they don't exactly align with the normal Google image results.

Comment: This seems to be a python related question and not about batch-files. I'll update the tags for you, but I suggest reading at the info page of the tags you use.

Comment: Thanks @DennisvanGils

Comment: If you're looking for the reason the results from your own application are different from your regular Google image search, that's because Google changes the results based on your cookies etc, which your application doesn't have

Comment: @DennisvanGils More of a side note with the update. But thanks, I figured it was something like that. The main thing I need, as noted, is to be able to efficiently download the images from each of the image links, and if possible with the associated alt tags.

Comment: Not sure if you are still trying to make this work. However, Google will not only care about your cookies but also about your user agent string. Scraping Google is also not trivial because they consider it a violation of their terms and conditions and will quickly block you if they pick up on the scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ImageSoup module. To install it, simply:

```
pip install imagesoup
```

A sample code:

```
>>> from imagesoup import ImageSoup
>>>
>>> soup = ImageSoup()
>>> images_wanted = 50
>>> query = 'landscape'
>>> images = soup.search(query, n_images=50)
```

Now you have a list with 50 landscape images from Google Images. Let's play with the first one:

```
>>> im = images[0]
>>> im.URL
https://static.pexels.com/photos/279315/pexels-photo-279315.jpeg
>>> im.size
(2600, 1300)
>>> im.mode
RGB
>>> im.dpi
(300, 300)
>>> im.color_count
493230
>>> # Let's check the main 4 colors in the image. We use
>>> # reduce_size = True to speed up the process.
>>> im.main_color(reduce_size=True, n=4))
[('black', 0.2244), ('darkslategrey', 0.1057), ('darkolivegreen', 0.0761), ('dodgerblue', 0.0531)]
# Let's take a look on our image
>>> im.show()
```

[image]

```
>>> # Nice image! Let's save it.
>>> im.to_file('landscape.jpg')
```

The number of images returned by each search may change. Usually is a number smaller than 900. If you want to get all images, set n_images=1000.

To contribute or report bugs, check the github repo: https://github.com/rafpyprog/ImageSoup

Comment: Can you please correct your code? It does not work at all. Thanks.